# Temp table not returning the rows that it contains

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, temp-tables

I have a temp table stored in the `tempdb` of my server. When I do a sample `SELECT` like this, it returns the data which is partially displayed in the picture.

```
select top 10 * from ##FlowExecution
```

[image]

I then copy the value of the first `CustomerIdHash` to get its related data on the table.

```
select top 10 * from ##FlowExecution 
where CustomerIdHash = '0x913DF790B957B42A9867F3491E9B8C919F81B64DC1812FDDECB9F919DB15A5D1'
```

Surprisingly I get nothing in return and I am wondering why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'0x913DF790B957B42A9867F3491E9B8C919F81B64DC1812FDDECB9F919DB15A5D1'<> 0x913DF790B957B42A9867F3491E9B8C919F81B64DC1812FDDECB9F919DB15A5D1`. Your column is a `varbinary`, pass it a `varbinary`:

```
select top 10 * from ##FlowExecution 
where CustomerIdHash = 0x913DF790B957B42A9867F3491E9B8C919F81B64DC1812FDDECB9F919DB15A5D1;
```

Your query was effectively implicitly casting your `varchar` value to a `varbinary` value, resulting in the value `0x307839313344463739304239353742343241393836374633343931453942`

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary,'0x913DF790B957B42A9867F3491E9B8C919F81B64DC1812FDDECB9F919DB15A5D1');
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this.